# How to remove the dots in a certain section of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I'm currently writing a thesis using Classic Thesis template and I would like to avoid the dots that appear in the TOC of the part dedicated to the Annexes as is the case in the front matter part. More precisely, I've observed that the dots don't appear in the toc when it's a chapter or a section. They are only in the subsection and the subsubsection. Which code do I need to insert to do that ?

This is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\frontmatter
\begin{document}

    \backmatter
    \section{Conclusion générale}
    \bibnewpage 
\nocite{*}
{\raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex[npr] 
\printindex[mat]
\newpage
\appendix
\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{Roman}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
\setcounter{section}{}
\part*{Annexes}
\chapter{Entretiens cliniques}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cannot really get this Minimal **Working** Example to work...

Comment: Is it that difficult to create a running example? There's no `\begin{document}` And `classicthesis` should not be used, it contains many weird settings

Comment: Sorry. But why should classic thesis not be used ? And where are now the "weird settings" ?

Comment: There is not even a `\tableofcontents` statement in your document.  Your question does not show any effort.

Comment: The `classicthesis` package uses `tocloft` to modify the appearance of the TOC.  Please read the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) and come back if you managed to revise and improve your question.

Comment: Is there any news here?